# How does Node.js check maximum number of callbacks in timer phase?

Tags: node.js, libuv

In [node.org](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/), it says like this

> Each phase has a FIFO queue of callbacks to execute. While each phase is special in its own way, generally, when the event loop enters a given phase, it will perform any operations specific to that phase, then execute callbacks in that phase's queue until the queue has been exhausted or the maximum number of callbacks has executed. When the queue has been exhausted or the callback limit is reached, the event loop will move to the next phase, and so on.

But in the [Timers Phase](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/timer.c#L163), it seems that it does not have any methods of checking callback limits

it just check timers heap and execute callback.

How does Node.js check maximum number of callbacks in timer phase and move to the next phase?

Comment: How is this related to libuv?